# Java Button Action Command

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm creating a simple Minesweeper game in Java. Size 9x9.

I create an array of `JPanels` and an array of buttons; I add each button to its respective `JPanel`. then i add the `JPanels` to the `JFrame`.

How do i distinguish between each button on the action event?

Here's some of my code:

```
int gridx = 9;
int gridy = 9;
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[gridx*gridy];
JPanel[] jpanels = new JPanel[gridx*gridy];

public Minesweeper(){

    super("Minesweeper");


    setLayout(new GridLayout(9,9));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<gridx*gridy; i++){
        jpanels[i] = new JPanel();
        buttons[i] = new JButton();
        buttons[i].addActionListener(buttonEvent);
        jpanels[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        jpanels[i].add(buttons[i]);
        add(jpanels[i]);            
    }
    //buttons[67].setEnabled(false);
    setSize(300,300);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

The only way i can think about doing this is adding text to the button like so:

```
    buttons[i] = new JButton(i);
```

Then calling `getActionCommand()` but i dont want text to show up on the button. Any other ideas?

Comment: I suspect you can play with the [`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()) method of the `ActionEvent` object that you get when you get called back on your `ActionListener#actionPerformed` method stub.

Comment: You do not need `jpanels`, and here it might work better to leave out `panel` too, as the content pane got the GridLayout.

Comment: FYI, is there any particular reason why you're using a `JButton[]` instead of a `JButton[][]`? Sure you can map your `JButton[81]` to a `JButton[9][9]` but why would you?

Comment: Yeah i just switched it to a 2d array

Comment: @user3521471 With the 2d array now though you probably need `setActionCommand(i + "," + j);` and on the other end `String[] coords = getActionCommand().split(",");`

Comment: @Cruncher oh okay nice. I did that too. Now my problem is that when i click a button, it disappears, but i dont know how to add text to the jpanel behind it. Any ideas for that? The text would be the number of bombs the square touches.

Comment: @Cruncher Nevermind, i figured it out :)

Comment: @user3521471 just started typing haha

Comment: @Cruncher well if you remmeber what you were gonna say....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AbstractButton#setActionCommand](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29).

In your loop:

```
buttons[i].setActionCommand(i+"");
```

Then you'll get `i` back when you use `getActionCommand`

Note I did mention in a comment on another answer that I would create a new class `Mine` which `extends JButton` which I believe to be a better and more complete solution. This however gets the job done rather quickly.

Comment: Ahh! Yes, this does it. I didnt know you could set things other than strings in that. Thank you! I will mark yours as an accepted answer once i get enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @user3521471 You can only set `String` as the action command. The `i+""` converts `i` to a `String`. When you use `getActionCommand` you're going to have to convert it back to an integer.